# Blazor wasm: how to disable double tap zoom on iOS

Tags: css, ios, blazor

On my website, I have a numpad. I would like to disable double-tap zoom gesture for this element. Following what I found the web, I have tried to achieve this using css `touch-action`. But I could not make it work. Here below is the relevant code.

Thank you in advance for your help.

the css:

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    border: 1px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 2px;
}


.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
    border: 1px solid #575b5b;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.validate-icon {
    background-color: green;
}

.trash-icon {
    background-color: red;
}

.disable-dbl-tap-zoom {
    touch-action: manipulation;
}
```

and my razor code:

```blazor
<div class="grid-container disable-dbl-tap-zoom">

    @foreach (var i in new int[]{ 7, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 0})
    {
        var index = i;
        <div class="grid-item disable-dbl-tap-zoom" @onclick="() => DigitButtonClicked(index)">@i</div>
    }

    <div class="grid-item validate-icon disable-dbl-tap-zoom" @onclick="ValidateButtonClicked"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
    <div class="grid-item trash-icon disable-dbl-tap-zoom" @onclick="TrashButtonClicked"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check touch-action: manipulation; css on body.